# Is there a way to adjust the spawning position of the window panel in ursina on python?

Tags: python, position, ursina

Right now I already have the UI complete, but I cannot seem to figure out how to position it on the screen. I am fairly new to ursina, by the way.

Here is sample code:

```
app = Ursina()

test = InputField(text='')

UI = WindowPanel(
    title='Menu',
    content=(
        Text('Username:'),
        test,
        Button(text='Submit', color=color.azure),
        Button(text='Free Play'),
        Button(text='Challenge'),
        Button(text='Leaderboard')
        ),
        popup=True,
        enabled=True
    )

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `position` of your app (in pixels):

```py
app = Ursina(position=(100, 100))
```

Various other properties can be set as well, have a look at the [cheat sheet](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#Ursina).